# Overwrite YoastSEO meta-tags with another page's

Tags: wp-query, query, meta-query, seo, plugin-wp-seo-yoast

I'm writing a custom Wordpress theme and for a specific page I need to overwrite its meta-tags (printed by YoastSEO) with the meta-tags of another page I already know the ID of. I cannot just change the original page meta-tags because the replacement changes based off a custom field in the page.

I've tried this, but apparently wp_head() is unaffected by the_post()...

```php
    <head>
    ...
    <?php
    if (...)
    {
        $meta_page = new WP_Query([ 'page_id' => $meta_page_id ]);
        while ( $meta_page->have_posts() )
        {
            $meta_page->the_post();
            wp_head();
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
    else wp_head() ?>
    ...
    </head>
```

Hope it's clear enough; first question here.
Thanks in advance.